# Delete row from database c#

Tags: c#, database

Why is this code not working?

```
        (this.namesBindingSource.Current as DataRowView).Delete();         
        this.namesTableAdapter.Update(database1DataSet1);
```

Error : 
Update requires a valid DeleteCommand when passed DataRow collection with deleted rows.

Database is service-based database added to project with only one table which is show in dataGridView and this code is linked to button. You will click on row for delete and then pres button and get error....

What is wrong? I'm getting crazy......

Comment: What is the value of `namesTableAdapter.DeleteCommand` property?

Answer (score 2):

The error message is self explanatory. You need a valid `DeleteCommand` for `namesTableAdapter`. Otherwise it does not know you to delete your "deleted" rows. The same is true for `Update` or `Insert-Commands`.

`Delete()` just changes the [`RowState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate.aspx). If you use a `DataAdapter` (or `TableAdapter`) it needs to know what to do if the state is `Deleted` or `Modified`.

[**How to: Create TableAdapter Queries**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kda44dwy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: HI Tim, thank you very much for answer, but unfortunatelly I don´t have idea how to implemend this. I need to delete row from table when button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

use `CommandBuilder` but remember you need to use table with a key column in it.